# How to gain access to Windows Users folders on a read-only backup medium

Tags: backup, permissions, mount, ntfs

I have created a backup of a main (C:) volume of my old (Windows 7) computer and I am able to mount it as a read-only volume on my new (Windows 8.1) computer.

When I try accessing a user folder under C:\users\username... I get a dialog stating that I have no access rights, but can opt into getting permanent access by proceeding. After doing so, I get a new dialog telling me I still have no access.

I suspect it has to do with the read-only volume preventing some NTFS-changes. I am not able to make the volume writable (propitiatory cripple-ware backup software), and besides I would not want to forge history any way.

Is there any other way to gain access to these folders (other than purchasing a full product and making the volume write-enabled)?

Comment: Sounds like a UAC issue.  See if you can access the folder(s) with an elevated command line (like PowerShell), rather than Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried opening Explorer as admin which did not work, but via the command prompt (as administrator) I can reach the files! Another funny thing is that in Explorer the folder name "Users" is translated to dutch ("Gebruikers") while in dos it is left "Users". Crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a UAC issue. See if you can access the folder(s) with an elevated command line (like PowerShell), rather than Windows Explorer.  [The issue is that Windows Explorer does not behave "properly" with UAC](http://setspn.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-windows-explorer-together-with.html), so problems like this often result.

The linked article has a couple of workarounds, though personally, I prefer to just use a different program for file browsing... I was never a big fan of Windows Explorer to begin with.