# Accessing the user folder from a previous Windows installation (content on a read-only image)

Tags: windows, uac, read-only, home-folder

Before upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 I imaged the Windows 7 system using O&O DiskImage Professional. After a clean upgrade (wiped the original installation) I started restoring content, and eventually came across something I had forgotten to pull from my old personal folder before reinstall. To my surprise I couldn't access the \Users\MyOldFolder on the image, apparently because its Admin and user UUIDs were now different. As an admin on a new install I would normally just assume ownership of the old content and would be good to go, but the image is read-only so I can't alter the permissions on it.

My question is: Is there any way to access that content – i.e. as an admin of the Windows 10 Pro installation make Windows to ignore the offending old permissions? Or is my only option to write the image onto a disk so that I can modify the permissions as needed? I tried to turn UAC off but that did not make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question that I had already written, but hadn't yet posted by the time I came across the answer. There was a ~duplicate ([How to gain access to Windows Users folders on a read-only backup medium](https://superuser.com/questions/884619/how-to-gain-access-to-windows-users-folders-on-a-read-only-backup-medium)), but its answer did not help because turning UAC off made no difference in my case.

There was a solution, however:

1. Download and install [SysInternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) (specifically [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec), which is part of the suite).
2. Start [PowerShell with elevated privileges](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-open-an-elevated-powershell-prompt-in-windows-10).
3. If SysInternals suite (and specifically PsExec.exe) isn't on the path, navigate to the folder you installed it in.
4. Now execute `cmd` as **SYSTEM**:
   `psexec -s cmd.exe`
5. You're now able to access the content whose **Administrator** and **USER** UUIDs have changed due to the system reinstall (but which you can't modify because of the read-only media). You're now accessing it as the **SYSTEM** which does not change from install to install.

   Simply navigate to the mounted read-only media, and walk right in to the folder you were previously denied access to, like **R:\Users\MyOldFolder** (a user folder of the old Windows installation).

   You can then copy files out. I used `xxcopy` to copy my entire old profile folder from the read-only media into a folder on my hard drive so that I can easily retrieve missing program config files as I configure my new Windows 10 installation. **2022 update:** `xxcopy` was discontinued a few years ago, but you can use instead Windows' built-in `robocopy` to accomplish the same, like so: `robocopy c:/path/to/source d:/path/to/target *.* /COPY:D`, where `D` implies "Data only" (and no attributes, or the owner), as outlined in  [this superuser.com thread](https://superuser.com/a/1549775/36551).

I found the critical details for the above from a [TechNet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/32aa8bb8-fc31-4287-a463-65f974d1822b/analyzing-the-directories-denied?forum=winserverpowershell).

Comment: It's enough to elevate your app so that it runs with Administrator privileges. The problem is you can't elevate Explorer. Yet you can elevate Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`), Far Manager or another application.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I use [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/), and did first try to run it with Administrator privileges, but was still denied access to my old personal folder on the read-only image. Also, out of curiosity I just tried to run Directory Opus as SYSTEM (`.\PsExec.exe -s -i "C:\Program Files\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\dopus.exe"`), but Directory Opus still has no privileges to access the directory. Thus far only the Admin PowerShell elevated to SYSTEM has worked.

Comment: Weird! I have never tried to access a read-only file system, but accessing user profiles from a previous Windows installation has always worked with Administrator rights.